# cocoa mac nstextfield not editable with array controller object

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I am working on learning cocoa on the Mac.  I have a little app that has a text field, which is bound to an array controller (which is in turn bound to a core data managed object).

The idea is hat when the window loads, the details from the core data entity will be shown.  At this point however, there is no data in the core data entity for this NSWindow.

There are several labels and text fields and an NSImageView, all defined through Interface Builder.

When the NSWindow is displayed, all of the objects are shown.  However, only NSImageView is selectable.  None of the TextFields can be selected and none can be edited. I have read through numerous posts in SO and other places, but I cannot figure out why the textfield is not selectable.  It may be editable, but I don't know yet since i can't select it.

If I create a new project and only put the textfield on it, i can select it and edit it.  Since I have only been experimenting with cocoa and Xcode since Xcode 5 came out, I am lost on where to find the solution.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven’t inserted (or selected) a row in your array controller, so you’re trying to edit the values in nothing.